# How can I unnest a repeated record in BigQuery, with one array giving the column names and another giving column values?

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I am working in Google BigQuery and have a dataset with two repeated records: one is the element name and the other is the element value. A simplified version of my dataset (with just 2 entries) looks like this:

| globalId | Meta.name | Meta.value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9200000104 | ViewsL7D | 2877 |
|  | OldPrice | 33.47 |
|  | NewPrice | 33.21 |
| 9200000783 | ViewsL7D | 19231 |
|  | OldPrice | 14.27 |
|  | NewPrice | 12.11 |

What I want to get is a table like this:

| globalId | ViewsL7D | OldPrice | NewPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9200000104 | 2877 | 33.47 | 33.21 |
| 9200000783 | 19231 | 14.27 | 12.11 |

I haven't worked with repeated records before so I don't really know how to tackle this, but I have tried using the following code so far:
`SELECT * FROM table LEFT JOIN UNNEST(cloudmetadata)`

But when doing this I keep the repeated records and just add six extra columns, alternating between the names and values. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select globalId, 
  max(if(name = 'ViewsL7D', value, null)) as ViewsL7D,
  max(if(name = 'OldPrice', value, null)) as OldPrice,
  max(if(name = 'NewPrice', value, null)) as NewPrice
from your_table t, t.Meta
group by globalId
```

if applied to sample data in your question

[image]

output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can simply pivot the table

if you have more than these three meat name you have to use dynamic sql

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `globalId` varchar(10),
>   `Meta.name` VARCHAR(8),
>   `Meta.value` DECIMAL(10,2)
> );
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`globalId`, `Meta.name`, `Meta.value`)
> VALUES
>   ('9200000104', 'ViewsL7D', '2877'),
>   ('9200000104', 'OldPrice', '33.47'),
>   ('9200000104', 'NewPrice', '3321'),
>   ('9200000783', 'ViewsL7D', '19231'),
>   ('9200000783', 'OldPrice', '14.27'),
>   ('9200000783', 'NewPrice', '12.11');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `globalId`,
> MAX(IF (`Meta.name` = 'ViewsL7D',`Meta.value`, NULL  )) AS ViewsL7D,
> MAX(IF (`Meta.name` = 'OldPrice',`Meta.value`, NULL  )) AS OldPrice,
> MAX(IF (`Meta.name` = 'NewPrice',`Meta.value`, NULL  )) AS NewPrice
> FROM table1
>
> GROUP BY `globalId`
> ```
>
> ```
> globalId   | ViewsL7D | OldPrice | NewPrice
> :--------- | -------: | -------: | -------:
> 9200000104 |  2877.00 |    33.47 |  3321.00
> 9200000783 | 19231.00 |    14.27 |    12.11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=665d6db1a1e9bbb8b5d8879b621fc938)*

Answer (score 1):

Given the shape of your table, I suppose you have two arrays `name` and `value` kept in a `Meta` structure. I recreated the table with the following:

```
WITH
  mydata AS (
  SELECT
    9200000104 AS globalid,
    STRUCT(["ViewsL7D",
      "OldPrice",
      "NewPrice"] AS name,
      [2877,
      33.47,
      33.21] AS value) AS Meta
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    9200000783 AS globalid,
    STRUCT(["ViewsL7D",
      "OldPrice",
      "NewPrice"] AS name,
      [19231,
      14.27,
      12.11] AS value) AS Meta )
```

[image]

From there you want to unnest your array and pivot it:

```
SELECT
  globalid,
  MAX(IF(name="ViewsL7D",value, NULL)) AS ViewsL7D,
  MAX(IF(name="OldPrice",value, NULL)) AS OldPrice,
  MAX(IF(name="NewPrice",value, NULL)) AS NewPrice
FROM
  (SELECT
    globalid,
    Meta.name[OFFSET(offset_value)] name,
    Meta.value[OFFSET(offset_value)] value
  FROM mydata,
  UNNEST(Meta.value) value WITH OFFSET offset_value ORDER BY offset_value)
GROUP BY globalid 
ORDER BY
  globalid
```

It gives this
[image]